# Magento2 - Adobe XD to Magento2 font size

Tags: layout, design, page-layouts, fonts

On the `xd` design the font-size is `55` and when I apply this font-size in my Magento layout It is bigger ?

Why is it so?

Comment: Please check : https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd/font-size-differs-in-web-browser-as-compared-to-xd/td-p/10534752?page=1

Comment: You have to scale font size according to the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is resolutions on retina displays work the same as on
> mobile devices - they use scaling.

Your logical resolution is 1440x900, and 1920x1080 is bigger than that, so when you open the prototype everything looks smaller as it's scaled down to fit. 1366 naturally fits, as it's smaller, and you see it at 100% - everything matches.